# How do I get a column of a dataframe as a series

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I have the following code:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars_lazy::prelude::*;

pub fn main() -> Result<(), PolarsError> {
    let df = df! (
        "start" => &[3, 8, 5],
        "end" => &[6, 9, 7],
        "idx" => &[0, 1, 2],
    )?;
}
```

How do I get "start" as a series? I can't see a to_series or anything.

Answer (score 1):

That was easy:

```
let s = df.column("start").unwrap();
print!("{}", s);
```

Answer (score 1):

[rust-polars](/questions/tagged/rust-polars) DataFrame has `Index` trait implementations for [`&str`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#impl-Index%3C%26str%3E-for-DataFrame) and [`usize`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#impl-Index%3Cusize%3E-for-DataFrame).

```
impl Index<&str> for DataFrame
impl Index<usize> for DataFrame
```

This means that you could use `&df["start"]` or `&df[0]` to get the `start` column as a series.

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

pub fn main() -> Result<(), PolarsError> {
    let df = df! (
        "start" => &[3, 8, 5],
        "end" => &[6, 9, 7],
        "idx" => &[0, 1, 2],
    )?;

    let by_str = &df["start"];
    let by_usize = &df[0];

    println!("{by_str}");
    println!("{by_usize}");
    Ok(())
}
```

This will print:

```
shape: (3,)
Series: 'start' [i32]
[
        3
        8
        5
]
shape: (3,)
Series: 'start' [i32]
[
        3
        8
        5
]
```